# Multiple configuration files with Nginx

Tags: python, nginx

I am running two flask websites. They are running through gunicorn and I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy to these two applications. For some reason when I have the two nginx configurations in two separate files ([site config 1](https://gist.github.com/GabeMeister/058b7dfd1e42ec6163c6be7f687b9b62) and [site config 2](https://gist.github.com/GabeMeister/2485ddb4532c049492f65af395695164)), nginx seems to only use the first one. However, if I put both of the website configurations in [1 file](https://gist.github.com/GabeMeister/e132f7ac5c811b31aacdcc16c9b3be0e), then each website works just fine when I visit them in the browser.

Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: You can test the configuration and see exactly which files `nginx` is reading with: `nginx -T`

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I just forgot to create a soft link for the two files in the `sites-enabled` directory.

@Richard Smith thanks for letting me know about the `-T` option, very useful.